# Access $el inside a computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to access this.$el.offsetTop in a computed property, but get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined
```

How can I access the offsetTop of the component in a computed method? if this is not possible then is there an alternative?

Component:

```
<template>
    <div :class="{ 'active' : test }"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {

    computed: {

        test() {
           console.log(this.$el.offsetTop);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Show the component?

Comment: The computed may be being evaluated before mounting time. Test for existence of `$el`.

Comment: Have edited to add component.

Comment: Roy J - ReferenceError: $el is not defined - so I guess it does not exist - how to fix?

Answer (score 13):

If a computed property is used in the template, its method will fire before the Vue instance is mounted, so `this.$el` will be `undefined`.

If your computed property is dependant on some property of `this.$el`, you can set it to a data property in the `mounted` hook (where `this.$el` will be defined).

In your case:

```
<template>
  <div :class="{ 'active' : test }"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { offsetTop: null };
  },
  computed: {
    test() {
      console.log(this.offsetTop);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.offsetTop = this.$el.offsetTop;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wanted it in computed so I could get the value at the time, so at one point it may be 100px from top, another 200px and so on... The above solution only sets the offsetTop once.

Comment: Computed properties will only update when dependent data properties on the Vue instance are changed. A computed property won't update in response to a change on `this.$el`, since Vue doesn't have a baked-in way to detect and respond to any changes to the root DOM element. There might be plugins that support it, or you might have to watch the offsetTop manually.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did to solve this problem:

I set an `el` property to `null` in the component's `data`, and in the mounted hook, I set `this.el` to `this.$el`. Then, in the computed property, I check `this.el` before trying to access its properties to avoid an error during the first render. So, in the context of your example we'd have:

```
<template>
    <div :class="{ 'active' : test }">{{test}}</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: {
        el: null,
    },

    computed: {
        test() {
            return this.el ? this.el.offsetTop : 0;
        }
    },

    mounted(){
        this.el = this.$el;
    }
}
</script>
```

As a side note, I don't believe you have access to the console in Vue.js computed properties, so I removed that bit.